# Git - exclude a path when listing stash changes?

Tags: git

Is there a way to examine stashed changes (`git stash list -p`) and exclude *package-lock.json* for example?

It says that the `list` command takes same options as `git log` but can't find anything relevant on the [git log documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

`git stash list -p --exclude=package-lock.json` doesn't work - I still see the stashed changes in *package-lock.json*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--exclude` is meant for excluding particular *references*.  You want the `git diff` option that excludes particular *path names*, `:(exclude)package-jock.json`.

It looks as though `git stash list` invokes `git log` this way, though:

```
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m "$@" $ref_stash --
```

The pathspec options, such as `:(exclude)` would go *after* the `--`.  So you'll need to use `git log` directly:

```
git log --format="%gd: %gs" -g --first-parent -m -p refs/stash -- ":(exclude)package-lock.json"
```

Comment: Tip: for _all_ files with same name in any subdirectory just prepend the filename with a star: `":(exclude)*package-lock.json"`

Comment: @montrealist: use `**/` for general niceness, but note that I have not tested this.

Comment: Sadly `**/` doesn't work. Also removed `--format="%gd: %gs"` - it was complaining when used inside a git alias.

Comment: Be careful with quotes inside `.gitconfig` as `.gitconfig` has its own usage of quotes. Double quotes that must pass through must be expressed as backslash-doublequote. You can use single quotes in some cases, though here just `alias lx = log --format=\"%gd: %gs\" ...` works well.

Comment: @montrealist If youre using stash often enough to need an alias for this, I’d consider re-examining your workflow. I gently phased stash out of mine and only rarely use it now